# create a cache key based on location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

All,

I am trying to use cache to avoid request over http when the request is made for a specific area.

For example, your are in Los Angeles and 3 persons around you ( appx 1miles) make a google search about gas station nearby.

Instead of requesting each time, it's faster to allow people who are close to you and making the same search to get the result already cached.

In a previous method, I am caching using Redis and build a key using the parameters but to re-use it, you need an exact match as the key created was based on "gas_station__"

```
 def set_cache key, val
    return if blank?( key ) || blank?( val )

    connection.set key, val
    connection.expire key, EXPIRY
  end

  def get_cache key
    connection.get( key ) if present?( key )
  end
```

now I have used the Ruby Gem geocode api and when giving a coordinate and distance, it give me back a range of lat/lon

```
  Geocoder::Calculations.bounding_box(location, distance)
```

and using the api below:

```
def isLocationInRange(location, area)
  if location[0].between?(area[0], area[2]) && location[1].between?(area[1], area[3])
    return true
  end
  false
end
```

I am able to know if the location gave in isLocationInRange is inside the "area"

the issue now is to connect this logic to Redis and use it to re-use the cache.

the best should be to generate a Redis key and look for it but it's not easy as I do not want to parse each key stored and check one by one the lat/lon params defined to see if that match an already known range of location.

Comment: another option could be to generate a unique lat, long when the lat/long received is in the same area.  any position inside a radius from the center always report the same lat/long.

Comment: A completely different solution (better imho) is to picture a grid on the globe. Your solution than consists of 2 steps: 1) given lat/long determine identifier of grid-cell (at a particular resolution). and possibly the 8 neighboring cells 2) store your stuff per grid-cell id in redis for a quick lookup or something. A nice way to create grids over a globe is [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). There's probably some libs in ruby to use. Apparently even [redis](https://redis.io/commands/geohash) has some support, although I don't know if that last one is useful. hth.

Answer (score 0):

### Gemfile

```
gem 'redis'
```

Run bundle install

### config/redis.yml

```
default: &default
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  db: 15

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

### config/initializers/redis.rb

```
redis_config = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(Rails.application.config_for(:redis))
REDIS = Redis.new(host: redis_config[:host], port: redis_config[:port], db: redis_config[:db])
```

Now REDIS variable is available throughout your application since initializer files are loaded on app load.

```
REDIS.set("gas_station__#{some_location}", latitude_values here)
REDIS.get("gas_station_#{some_location}")
```

References: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb